# Duas funções SUM no Oracle SQL para retornar duas somas diferentes com dois SELECT

Tags: sqldeveloper

Estou executando o os seguintes select no Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT SUM(FANFISCA.TOTAL_NF) AS TOTAL_FATURAMENTO,
FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE

FROM FANFISCA,GEEMPRES

WHERE GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA = FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT

GROUP BY FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT, GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO


UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_FATURAMENTO) AS TOTAL_PEDIDO,
FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE

FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES

WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA

AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE BETWEEN '05' AND '15'

GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO,FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT
```

Segue abaixo resultado da consulta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso retornar a TOTAL_FATURAMENTO e TOTAL_PEDIDO em 2 colunas diferentes, como podem ver na imagem, a consulta retorna todos na mesma coluna do TOTAL_FATURAMENTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não utilize UNION pois ele serve para obter dados exatamente da forma que você postou e que não te atende.

Tente:

```
SELECT COD_REPRESENTANTE, REPRESENTANTE, TOTAL_FATURAMENTO, TOTAL_PEDIDO FROM
(SELECT SUM(FANFISCA.TOTAL_NF) AS TOTAL_FATURAMENTO,
            FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FANFISCA,GEEMPRES
WHERE GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA = FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT
GROUP BY FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT, GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO) foo

FULL OUTER JOIN

(SELECT SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_FATURAMENTO) AS TOTAL_PEDIDO,
            FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES
WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE BETWEEN '05' AND '15'
GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO,FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT) bar
ON foo.COD_REPRESENTANTE = bar.COD_REPRESENTANTE;
```

Creio que um ORDER BY seja útil para organizar o resultado.

Comment: Isso funcionou muito bem, mas ocorre um erro de ambiguidade quando deixamos COD_REPRESENTANTE, REPRESENTANTE dentro do 1º SELECT.
Quando removemos e deixamos dessa forma SELECT TOTAL_PEDIDO,TOTAL_FATURAMENTO FROM retorna os dados corretos, mas é claros sem a presença das variáveis COD_REPRESENTANTE, REPRESENTANTE.

Alguma idéia de como podemos resolver isso??

Comment: Como são iguais, a menos que não exista em uma das tabelas, você pode utilizar: `COALESCE(foo.COD_REPRESENTANTE,  bar.COD_REPRESENTANTE), COALESCE(foo.rEPRESENTANTE,  bar.REPRESENTANTE)`.

Comment: Onde vou aplicar essa função COALESCE?
Seria dessa forma:
SELECT TOTAL_PEDIDO,TOTAL_FATURAMENTO,
COALESCE(foo.COD_REPRESENTANTE, bar.COD_REPRESENTANTE), COALESCE(foo.REPRESENTANTE, bar.REPRESENTANTE)
FROM ?

Ou tenho que aplicar esse COALESCE abaixo do SELECT de cada SUM?

Comment: Na lista do select mais externo: `SELECT COALESCE(foo.COD_REPRESENTANTE, bar.COD_REPRESENTANTE) COD_REPRESENTANTE, COALESCE(foo.REPRESENTANTE, bar.REPRESENTANTE) REPRESENTANTE, TOTAL_FATURAMENTO, TOTAL_PEDIDO FROM ...`

Comment: Muito Obrigado irmão!
Funcionou perfeito aqui.